# When 0xFF is in char array, it gets read as integer along with next char

Tags: c, arrays, char, dos, turbo-c

I am using C on MS-DOS, specifically Turbo C, and I encountered something strange with my numbers being read here. I have a function called writeBitmap that in essence takes a struct with a path, x and y size, and then offset for a sprite sheet, as well as an array that defines each image using this.

The problem I am having is when I reiterate over the cached image data I get from a file, the output from the array always gets read as if it were an integer if it starts with FF. What I mean by this, is if there is an FF in my array, when I use an if statement to test to see if it's there it acts like it's reading an integer containing the FF, and then the next character concatenated. This means that I can't detect an FF (which is a transparency byte by the way) because whenever it's present, it reads it and then the next byte at the same time, even when casted to a char.

Here is my code, I am omitting some stuff, but up top I have this information:

```
#include <dos.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* define structs */
struct imageFile {
    char path[16];
    unsigned short size_x;
    unsigned short size_y;
    char offset;
};

/*define globals */

struct imageFile imgMap[1] = 
{
    {"./OUTP.DAT", 24, 24, 8}
};
```

These are the variables that are important to the function, and this is the function as written:

```
void writeBitmap(unsigned x, unsigned y, unsigned id){
    int i, j, k;
    int imgSize = (imgMap[id].size_x * imgMap[id].size_y); /*get size, init     cache, and open file to offset*/
    char *imgCache = (char *)malloc(imgSize);
    FILE *fimg;
    if(x + imgMap[id].size_x > 321 || y + imgMap[id].size_y > 201){
        return;
    }
    fimg = fopen(imgMap[id].path, "rb");
    fseek(fimg, (imgMap[id].offset * imgSize), SEEK_SET);
    fread(imgCache, 1, imgSize, fimg);
    fclose(fimg);
    k = 0;

    for(i = 0; i < imgMap[id].size_y; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < imgMap[id].size_x; j++){
            if((char)imgCache[k] != 0xFFFF){
            /*setPixel(x + j, y + i, (char)imgCache[k]);*/
            printf("%x ", imgCache[k]);
            }/*else printf("TRANS: %x\n", imgCache[k]);*/
            k++;

        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

setPixel refers to another function that is known working. It just calculates segment and offset for graphics mode 0x13 and then writes to memory.

So, I currently have this code set up in a bit of a debug state. I have it print something if it's not 0xFFFF, which eliminates anything read as an integer. If try to eliminate anything that's 0xFF, it doesn't eliminate it.

Here's the screen output from that: [image: Screen output]

As you can see, everything that's not 0xFF gets printed as a 1 byte char, but if there is a 0xFF, it gets read like it's an integer along with the next byte of data.

I have no clue how this could even happen. I have a feeling it might be my dynamically allocated array, but it's of type char, and it shouldn't read more data than a byte at a time per array member.

Comment: ... why are you still using Turbo C?

Comment: A `char` is only one byte, so this statement doesn't make sense: `if((char)imgCache[k] != 0xFFFF)`. Also, no need to cast here. And no need to cast the return of `malloc`  in C.

Comment: It is curious that code is having trouble,yet the return value of input functions are not checked,  especially `fread()`.  I'd expect that as a first step.

Comment: fread should only ever return a byte at a time as programmed.

Also, that's the problem I am having. It refuses to read anything on the character level if it begins with FF, it just reads as an integer even if I directly cast it to a char, and read it from a malloc character array.

Also, I program in Turbo C just because I find entertainment in doing so. Just a hobby programming using a dead tool.

Comment: I couldn't help but notice the phallicness of this post.

Comment: @MFisherKDX In 16-bit land `(char)imgCache[k] != 0xFFFF` makes sense.  It is a value compare, not a bit pattern compare.

Comment: `printf("%x ", imgCache[k]);` you are trying to print a `char` as an `int`.

Comment: That shouldn't matter. If it's a char, it will only get printed as a char, and it shouldn't read more data. Even still, in what should only be a comparison of chars, it over-reads.

Comment: @MichaelPetch [Sometimes a Banana is just a Banana.](https://kennethmarkhoover.me/2012/07/23/sometimes-a-banana-is-just-a-banana-and-a-story-is-just-a-story/)

Comment: Too much assembly programming does that to ones mind...

Comment: is `imgSize` what you expect it to be?

Comment: Did you try `unsigned char *imgCache` ?

Comment: @yano
Yes, under normal operations (where transparency is not concerned) it works perfectly fine. It even works fine with the 0xFFFF comparison using transparency, except in a few situations (like there there is a 0xFF next to a non 0xFF byte.

Comment: Your 'char' gets implicitly converted to int. The 'ffb0' lines aren't because the char is 0xff, they are because the char is 0xb0.

Comment: As @Art said, that is signed extension for you.

Comment: You will see this issue only if the first nibble is greater than `8` I assume.

Comment: Which is why you use correct types in your printfs instead of saying "That shouldn't matter".

Comment: The printf is just for debugging.

Comment: Alright, many thanks. One strange thing I have now just noticed, is that it actually was working fine to display transparency as written before, and that my test was fault. It's a case of, it doesn't work, why? turning into, it now works, and then the other thing actually did work, why?

Would be sweet if someone could make a answer so i can mark it as the right one. Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `%x` format specifier expects an `int`. printf() includes default argument promotion of its arguments to `int`. So unless you explicitly tells it that the input should be treated as a char, it won't. `int` is 16 bits on  your system, therefore 2 bytes get printed.

The root of the problem is that `char` is entirely unsuitable to use for anything but characters. It has implementation-defined signedness - on Turbo C it was the same as signed char. So when you store a value larger than 0x7F in it, you invoke an implementation-defined conversion to `signed char`, ending up with a negative value.

The solution is to use `uint8_t` from `stdint.h` instead. Since you aren't using a professional standard C toolchain, but rather a non-standard one from the Jurassic period, you have to `typedef unsigned char uint8_t` instead.

When you use `uint8_t`/`unsigned char`, there won't be any negative sign preservation in printf's conversion to `int` and you'll get the expected output.

Comment: "The `%x` format specifier expects an `int`" --> "The `%x` format specifier expects an `unsigned int`"

Comment: First off, thanks for the answer

Turbo C doesn't appear to have stdint.h included with it, so I do not seem to be able to use this feature, unless I am misunderstanding what you are talking about

However, for my uses, unsigned char looks like it's working, as you are describing, so many thanks again.

Comment: @Ampera : Not all versions of Turbo-C came with `stdint.h` however over the years ones were developed to work in that environment among others: http://www.azillionmonkeys.com/qed/stdint.h

Comment: @Ampera That's what I told you. You aren't using a professional tool chain so you cannot code in standard C. Why don't you get an _absolutely free_, modern standard compiler and use it with your _absolutely free_, favourite modern IDE?